Integrating Additional 5.1 Audio into HLS Manifest: Providing Stereo and Surround Sound Options without Re-encoding
How can I include extra 5.1 audio to an already-existing HLS manifest without undergoing re-encoding? Initially, I encoded the video with stereo audio, where the audio was merged into the video file without a separate audio track. However, I now possess a 5.1 audio track in WAV format that I wish to integrate into the primary HLS manifest. I aim to provide users with the choice between the two available audio options: 'stereo' and 'surround'. Could you guide me through this process using the AWS MediaConvert console?
I attempted to achieve this using AWS MediaConvert by encoding the 5.1 audio and adding its URI to the master manifest. However, the process did not produce the desired outcome.

To achieve your goal of having both audio types available with all video rendition(s), you will need a new parent HLS manifest. Rewriting the parent manifest is a valid option. Retranscoding the entire asset will also generate a new parent manifest and is generally less effort for most people.
When you mix embedded and separate audio tracks, some players may ignore (not offer) the separate audio rendition. Best practice is to have each audio and video track in a separate file group and listed as such in the parent manifest.
If you choose to generate only the surround segments and then edit the existing parent manifest, the updated parent manifest should resemble:
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2083792,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1835949,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=24.000
MOV_1920x800muxed.m3u8
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="surround",LANGUAGE="eng",NAME="Alternate Audio",AUMOVELECT=YES,DEFAULT=NO,CHANNELS="6",URI="MOV_1920x800surround.m3u8"

The above manifest works. VLC player and hls.js both recognize the two audio tracks. Note, hls.js cannot decode AC3 but did detect its presence. It will be up to the PLAYER regarding whether it offers the viewer the option to switch to the provided surround-sound track.
For most users, retranscoding the asset with discrete video and audio tracks is the easier option.
